# Can we place @tag above background step in cucumber feature file

Tags: cucumber-java

I have a situation where for reporting purpose I want to add a tag to background, so if let's say couple of tests fail while execution on background step I have clear failure in report by tag.

I have tried following but it gives me a parsing error on runtime.

```
@Tag
Background: Background of test
When do abc
Then assert xyz
```

It throws me following error:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to parse resource
```

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you can put a tag on feature or scenario level, not step level. Assuming that the background is used for a particular (set of) feature(s) or scenario(s), tagging those should work.